# How can I parse a config file using XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl

Perl snippet:

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple(
    KeyAttr=>{
        property => 'propertyname',          
    },
    ForceArray => 1,
    ContentKey => '-content');

my $config = $xml->XMLin($configFile);
```

Configfile looks like:

```
<config>
<property propertyname="text1" b="text2" c="text3" d="text4">
 text5
</property>
<property propertyname="text6" b="text7" c="text8" d="text9">
 text10
</property>
</config>
```

How do I parse this config file so that `c` becomes a key and I can access the corresponding `b` and `d`? What does `KeyAttr` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XML::Simple` returns a Perl data structure (see [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)) which you can visualize using [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).
Here is one way to access the data you need:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;

my $xfile = '
<config>
<property propertyname="text1" b="text2" c="text3" d="text4">
 text5
</property>
<property propertyname="text6" b="text7" c="text8" d="text9">
 text10
</property>
</config>
';

my $xml = new XML::Simple(
    KeyAttr=>{
        property => 'propertyname',          
    },
    ForceArray => 1,
    ContentKey => '-content');

my $config = $xml->XMLin($xfile);

print "$config->{property}{text1}{c}\n";
print "$config->{property}{text6}{c}\n";
print "$config->{property}{text1}{d}\n";
print "$config->{property}{text6}{d}\n";
```

Output:

```
text3
text8
text4
text9
```

You can read about `KeyAttr` from [perldoc XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer perldoc XML::Simple . Explains the usage KeyAttr => {a => b}. Many tutorials only explain KeyAttr=>a usage.